# a web server for wakeonlan with user-specific permissions

Tags: web-services, ldap

I was wondering if there is a web-server tool inspired on [gwakeonlan](https://www.muflone.com/gwakeonlan/english/), but supporting LDAP login. So that you can only turn on your own computers as defined by the permissions set by a network system admin. (And possibly also turn them off or sleep via ssh+sudo.)
The motivation is energy/money saving, very often people don't turn off a computer overnight after leaving work because they will need it tomorrow when they will work from home. So I was thinking of a web-intranet tool to solve these issues.

Concerning the 'local subnet issue' of WOL, it should ideally support having some 'always turned on computers for each subnet' through which to route the requests to multiple subnets if necessary, as well as direct WOL packet sending by routers for those manufacturers that do support it, and/or targeted broadcasting that routers can forward.